# In an standalone app'., where the business logic must reside?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I read Tom Kyte's "Effective Oracle by Design". There he says to write most of the code in the DB itself to reduce application code. It is good in a distributed environment, but is it advantageous in an standalone application also?

My app. is in .NET.

Comment: I'm not an Oracle expert, but I think for any RDBMS it will depend on the application and the environment, as well as the code.  Any row-level processing is normally best done in the application, but set-based logic works best in a relational DB. Can you provide some info on what your app does and what sort of code/logic you are talking about?

Comment: @JNK: My app. is an standalone Windows app. It is an Inventory and Invoicing solution. At present, I wrote classes containing methods to perform various DB operations like Insert, Update and Delete. I wonder, if I could write stored procedures in the DB itself and only pass parameters via .NET front-end, what advantage it might give?

Comment: Looks like Tony addresses that eloquently below.  The biggest thing is consistency - future versions of the app will use the exact same queries and perform that same regardless of who end up maintaining the code.  If the SQL Logic is in the application, it is more likely to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***IF*** your database will only ever support a single application, and ***IF*** you never expect the same data to have different use cases depending who is using it, and ***IF*** you are never ever planning to use a different storage mechanism... then sure put business logic in the databse.

However, if any of those are true (as I suspect). Then I, and probably most people on this site, would strongly advise you against going down this path.

Putting logic in the DB can be seductive as you think "I can change this on the fly!" but it is a maintenance road you don't want to walk down. Listen to the voice of experience and keep your concerns separate.

> My app. is an standalone Windows app.
>   It is an Inventory and Invoicing
>   solution. At present, I wrote classes
>   containing methods to perform various
>   DB operations like Insert, Update and
>   Delete. I wonder, if I could write
>   stored procedures in the DB itself and
>   only pass parameters via .NET
>   front-end, what advantage it might
>   give?

This doesn't actually sound like business logic to me at all, unless of course you are doing something more than just CRUD operations. In that case, then whether or not you use stored procedures, an ORM, or manually generated queries in code is an implementation detail.

The data access layer should care about connecting to the data storage mechanism, but the rest of your application shouldn't care. I'll illustrate with an example:

```
public class MyDomainObject
{
    public String Name {get; set;}

    public Boolean IsValid()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Name) &&
           DoesNotContainInvalidCharacters(Name);
    }
}

public class MyDataAccess
{
    public List<MyDomainObject> GetAll()
    {
        //Some data access logic here
    }

    public MyDomainObject GetByName(String name)
    {
        //Some data access logic here
    }

    public void Save(MyDomainObject)
    {
        if(MyDomainObject.IsValid)
        {
            //Some data access logic here
        }
    }
}
```

So now you have a **domain object** and a **data access** object. The domain object enforces some trivial business logic that can be checked via the IsValid property, and the data access layer uses that to determine if it should be saved or not. However, the details of how data is stored don't really matter to the domain/business layer.

If you want to refactor to use stored procedures, then your application shouldn't really care.

Comment: Ok. Great. Do u have anything to say on my comment added to OP?

Answer (score 6):

Yes there are lots of advantages to putting the business logic in the Oracle database even for a standalone application:

- Performance and scalability, where the business logic involves accessing or updating the database
- Dependency tracking: references to tables and other objects in your code are easily found
- PL/SQL is **designed** for writing code that accesses the database, very simply, and without the need for building lots of dynamic SQL prepared statements, or using an obfuscating layer like Hibernate to do it for you.

I would actually steal some of Josh's answer and turn it 180 degrees:

> IF your database will only ever
>   support a single application, and IF
>   you never expect the same data to have
>   different use cases depending who is
>   using it... then sure put business
>   logic in the...

**application.**

I mean, do you seriously want two different applications to access the same rows of data but apply **different** rules to changes to that data?  What's the point of having a "rule" if you can break it just by using a different access path?

Note that I omitted this part of Josh's answer:

> ...IF you are never ever planning to
>   use a different storage mechanism...

Of course, **if** you are planning to support multiple databases, or to throw away Oracle and start using SQL Server or something else entirely to store your data, then you won't want to use PL/SQL to write your code.  But in many, many cases that is not going to happen and you would be ill-advised to pursue database independence for its own sake.

Comment: @Tony: I am going to stick with one product. Are there any performance benefits? However I don't think it has.

Comment: There may well be performance benefits: less round trips from the app to the database to get bits of data to use in your business logic; static rather than dynamic SQL (less parsing).  On the other hand, some really complex, intensive maths processing will be faster in other languages (or so I understand).

Comment: @Tony: clearly we have philisophical differences when it comes to this, but I have almost never worked on a database that **wasn't** accessed by multiple applications. Each needing their own set of business rules. In the end it takes some careful planning to make sure you are not bleeding application logic into the database. Some rules make more sense to be enforced at the DB level, but only those rules that apply to data integrity. Application logic should be left where it belongs.

Comment: @Josh, nor have I (worked on a database that wasn't accessed by multiple apps).  But (and maybe this is different with Oracle rather than other DBMSs) that isn't a problem: each app can, if necessary, have its own "schema" of business logic packages on the database, accessing the central schema of data.  So you might have an HR database with an HR application on top of it, and a project tracking system that accesses the HR database for info, and both would have some packages implementing their specific business rules.  You get all the separation of concerns you could wish for!

Comment: @Tony: After looking at your profile I believe we have touched on something else here. Use what you are going to be most comfortable and most productive in. In my case it is code because that is what I do. I use .Net to work in and the Database is there for persistence. You would undoubtedly run circles around me on any DBMS... When I run into a problem I reach for C# because I know how to make it sing, and you probably reach for PL/SQL for the same reasons :)

Comment: As a totally unbiased observer... I find I agree more with Tony on this point ;)